# how to emulate a user clicking on the scroll navigation

Tags: javascript, python, user-interface, scroll

I'm updating this question to be more inline with what I have now found to be the requirement.

Previously I used `setintervalTimer` to create a scroll event, using `window.scrollTo`, this is not an option as the currently running JavaScript on the page causes the scroll to be very laggy.

Is this possible?

1. I am hoping to find a way to interact with the browser by simulating the user clicking on the browser scroll bar and it being dragged to the bottom of the page. This is to screen record the whole website and all its interactions.

If there is another way this can be achieved (please rember JS is not a performant option right now) - then please let me know.

Thanks -
Wally

Comment: Probably because you are using the smooth scrolling behavior and yet you are calling it every 50ms or so: probably so fast that the previous scrolling animation is not done yet. Meanwhile a screen recording is going to be CPU intensive and may of course lead to dropped frames. Some screen recording software may even throttle the frame rate to avoid causing too much for a performance hit.

Comment: Disabling smooth scroll sadly did not increase performance - and you are correct, calling the scroll multiple times via interval timer is causing lag because of performance, which is what I am trying to solve. One option that I had tried to find (and couldn't) - was to use window.scrollTo <<< but give it an option of how long it should take to scroll there , sadly I dont think this is possible - thanks for you input :)

Comment: You've added a Python tag, so if that is what you'd like to use to implement a solution, you can use Python fairly easily to control mouse movements.

https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-drags

I would check that out and see if it helps. I'm betting that unless you're willing to put in a lot more effort, you'll need the scrollbar to always be in the same location and hard code the locations into a script.

Let me know if you need me to write up a detailed solution, if you have trouble coding it yourself.

Comment: I'm struggling to see why you are saying js isn't an option. Scrolling the page via js is trivial and not expensive in the slightest - do you have lots of scroll event listeners or code which is causing a repaint on scroll?

Comment: Just scroll using the scroll wheel (mouse).

Comment: @JakeWhiteley thanks for the question: Yes there multiple scroll events and the goal is to scroll over the whole page over say 20 seconds, not simply to just scroll to the bottom of the page, this requires the scroll event to be fired via an interval timer and with the currently running JS on the page causes serious lag and/or jumps - I would have assumed that JS would have provided an option to scrollTo({X, amount of time}) - but it seems not - unless you know of a way to do this on a single JS event?

Comment: @SandrinJoy until I have the hands of a surgeon to keep the scroll smooth an consistent this is not an option.....

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to simulate the user clicking on the scrollbar, but there is a native javascript way to smooth-scroll.

If you want to scroll to a specific y-coordinate or x-coordinate on the page, then use this:

```
// "Top" is y-coordinate
// "Left is x-coordinate
window.scroll({
  top: 100, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Or, if you want to scroll a certain amount from where you already are, you can use this:

```
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 100, // could be negative
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Lastly, if you want to scroll to a certain HTML5 element, you can use this:

```
document.querySelector('.exampleElement').scrollIntoView({ 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Here is an example (For the example I am using a bunch of line breaks make the page scrollable):

```js
document.querySelector('#here').scrollIntoView({ 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h1>Not Here!</h1>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h1 id="here">Here!</h1>
```

#### EDIT: These methods may only work on updated browsers

Comment: Thank you for the idea, sadly, as I had mentioned in my question, JS is not a performant option at present due to the nature of its single threaded call stack. This is a good idea and what I had already tried to implement in a way - You should note that this option does work for smooth scrolling but does not take into account the amount of time to scroll to the bottom of the page i.e. you cannot control the amount of seconds to reach the bottom of the page - this can be resolved by creating a interval timer to fire the scroll a few PX at a time each few ms , but this is resource intensive.